# PS Script to search all OU for "Servers" and move them to the "Servers" OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Currently my AD has about 20 or so Computer OUs across the various depts within my organization. These Computer OUs contain both Servers and Workstations  I would like a script that will search the entire AD domain to find any servers and then move them to the new "Servers" OU. We are working on some new tooling and need the servers to be in their own OU separate from workstations.

Comment: Nice, so what have you tried? Where at in **your** code are you having issues with this?

Comment: A quick Google search should yield some results on how to do this. If you already have some code and it's failing, please share it. If your asking for someone to write the code for you there are other platforms where people get paid for their skillset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter by OperatingSystem

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -like '*server*'" -SearchBase "CN=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=local" |
Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
```